# Date Range Picker autoApply:true doesn't work with timePicker: true

Tags: javascript, daterangepicker

I have this [Date Range Picker](http://www.daterangepicker.com) code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $('input[name="datefilter"]').daterangepicker({
                    autoApply: true,
                    timePicker: true,
                    locale: {
                        cancelLabel: 'Clear'
                    }
                });
                $('input[name="datefilter"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
                    $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY') + ' - ' + picker.endDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
                });
                $('input[name="datefilter"]').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
                    $(this).val('');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" name="datefilter" value="" />
    </body>
</html>
```

With specific emphasis on this line:

```
autoApply: true
```

Which according to this site: http://www.daterangepicker.com/ says:

> autoApply: (true/false) Hide the apply and cancel buttons, and automatically apply a new date range as soon as two dates are clicked.

But the datetimepicker that results 1) has both buttons (`Cancel` and `Apply`) still and 2) does not apply the change when two dates are clicked:

[image]

**WHILE WRITING THE QUESTION:**

I noticed that when I remove `timePicker: true` the desired `autoApply` behavior happens (the `Cancel` and `Apply` buttons disappear and the datepicker closes when dates are selected):

[image]

**So why does `autoApply` not work when `timePicker` is enabled?? I need both features.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That combination of options is not supported. If you "auto apply" as soon as they click two dates, you would be making the interface disappear before they've actually made their selection, as they've yet to select the time(s) they want. A button is needed to signify that they are done making their selection, which can require making up to 8 selections/clicks in various orders. You can only "auto apply" date ranges without times, since you know as soon as they choose both dates they're done.

Comment: Ok. Is there a way to force apply the selection if the focus of the date picker is lost?

Comment: That's the default behavior. It already does that if you click outside the picker, with no options.

Comment: Ok. My forms were submitting without the selected dates but it may be due to something else. I'll look at it and try to reproduce in another question if necessary. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Hi Dan... Is it possible to show just Cancel button without Apply. AutoApply will be true but Cancel button is still present ?

Comment: @StackAddict Did you find a way to do it?